# Facebook “Like Box” and JQuery

Tags: facebook, jquery

I'm attempting to add a FB "Like Box" to a website I'm developing. Not too familiar with Facebook apps, but so far I've gone the non-IFRAME route, using the FB SDK script include.

I'm fairly certain I've got almost everything setup correctly. In fact, I see the widget appear when I visit the page UNCACHED (i.e. in FF, I hit CTRL+SHIFT+R to reload all content to avoid loading from cache). Once I revisit the site, or move around within the site by clicking links, the content does not reappear.

I'm wondering if it's an issue with a) the channel.php file, or b) the apps interaction with my use of JQuery. The channel.php file is verbain what is provided by Facebook (using PHP's caching mechanism).

Here's the site currently: http://www.morningfatty.com/demo - It might be easier to list this rather than post several code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to your website and didn't see the like box.  I checked the HTML code and it all appeared fine.  The div looked like `<div data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-border-color="#40ADAD" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="light" data-width="192" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/morningfatty" class="fb-like-box"></div>`

I went to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and tried your link `http://www.facebook.com/morningfatty` and lo-and-behold the like box didn't display there.

I tried going directly to `http://www.facebook.com/morningfatty` and it redirected me to `http://www.facebook.com/MorningFatty`. I noticed the change of case in the name.  So I went back and tried `http://www.facebook.com/MorningFatty` in the like-box and **it worked!!**.

I believe that you page will work once you update the casing on the url.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated the div, like you mentioned, and I am still having the same issue unfortunately. I visited the FB link you posted [https://developers.../like-box] and put in both MorningFatty and morningfatty. Both worked fine for me in FF10.0. Now this is bizarre. I can check at work tomorrow as well, but could you tell me one thing... When on the page, are you able to use the JQuery links (such as clicking "Contact Us") and then go back to the "Home" page and still see the Like Box? That's the issue I'm having (in addition to it not appear unless I clear the cache).

Comment: Ahhhh I see, you don't have the plugin in the view source.  It appears you dynamically insert it later on (after Facebook has run it's parse on the DOM).  To get Facebook SDK to reparse the DOM, you will need to run FB.XFBML.parse(); after your dynamically insert the like-box into the side nav area.

Comment: That's exactly the problem - I added logic to call FB.XFBML.parse(id) after each link is clicked. Since the page content is fetched via JQuery, I included this in a callback function to ensure it occurs only after the page content is fetched. Thanks!!!